# Regex for multiple postcode parts

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex for matching the first part of a UK postcode:

```
/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

But I want to allow multiples of this, so need to check for entries like:

```
BT5,BT6,BT9, BT43, BT21
```

that is, multiple entries separated by a comma or a comma and a space.

What do I add to my regex to achieve this?

Comment: Is noise (like comma's) allowed between the postcodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that leading or trailing commas are not allowed, and that there needs to be at least one entry. That gives you:

```
/^\s*[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}(?:\s*,\s*[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})*\s*$/
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vX8wV2/2).

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
\s*       # Match optional whitespace
[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}   # Match one postcode
(?:       # Start of (repeated) noncapturing group:
 \s*,\s*  # Match a comma, optionally surrounded by whitespace
 [A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}  # Match one postcode
)*        # Repeat as needed (including zero times)
\s*       # Match optional whitespace
$         # End of string
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Well, it allows for trailing whitespace (which wasn't in the specs, but I hate webforms that fail because of surrounding whitespace). It can be left out (together with the first one) if leading/trailing whitespace should not be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Expand it like this (see the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/67)):

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}(?:, ?[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})*$
```

- After the first zip code, the non-capturing group `(?:, ?[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})*` matches zero or more times of...
- `, ?` a comma with an optional space...
- And another zip code `[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}`

In PHP:

```
$regex = '~^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}(?:, ?[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})*$~';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
    } 
else { // no match...
     }
```

Comment: FYI: added explanation, demo and sample PHP code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a regex like:

```
/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}/
```

Then you can use:

```
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}/", "BT5,BT6,BT9, BT43, BT21", $matches);
```

to retrieve an array of all matches.

If you want a regular expression that accepts only strings with some "noise" between the post codes, you can try:

```
/^([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})(, ?([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}))*$/
```

With `[ ,]` a list of characters allowed in between (like space and comma).

Comment: With the first regexp you only get **BT5** as a match. And the second one doesn't get the desired results either but just **BT5** and **BT21**.

Comment: Suffix `_all` was necessary.

Comment: Remove the **g** from your first regexp. That will cause an error if you have it.